# How long does it take to submit/approve a BigCommerce app?

Tags: shopify, bigcommerce

I'm thinking about making a BigCommerce app, and am wondering how long it takes to be reviewed and (hopefully) approved before it's live in the app store.

Earlier this year, I submitted a Shopify app and it was 3 weeks before they even reviewed it, and after fixing one minor bug, a total of 6 weeks from submission date to being live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of time from submission to approval does depend on the number of apps in queue as well as the response time from the app partner if there are any issues to correct.

A good rule of thumb is 2 weeks from submission to approval, but that time can be reduced if the app meets guidelines and there is good communication from the app partner. As long as the app meets BigCommerce guidelines, it should be a very streamlined process and can be done within a week:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#app-store-approval-requirements

Comment: Helpful, thank you.  Is there a way to see the length of the current "queue"?

Comment: The best way to find out the current queue and lead time would be to email the app marketplace team directly. The email address is appstore@bigcommerce.com

Answer (score 1):

Minimum amount of time required to get an app approved is 2 months from submission. This is based on personal experience in submitting the app in early 2018.

The first review email you get after submission (paying $99) is after 30 days. There after each email you send for clarification / feedback gets a reply from BigCommerce team after 7 days. Expect a cycle of atleast 4 to 5 emails before they publish the app.